# React Router 4 prevent pages from reloading

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

So here is my router structure:

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Route path="/" exact component={ Login } />
        <Route path="/timeline" component={ requireAuth(Timeline) } />
        <Route path="/chat/:id" component={ requireAuth(Chat) }/>
    </div>
</Router>
```

requireAuth() is a simple HOC component that makes an API call and based on the response renders `<ComposedComponent {...this.props} />` or `<Redirect to="/" />`

I am facing two problems:

1. requireAuth() gets called everytime I go from /timeline to /chat/XXX
2. When I go from /timeline to /chat/xxx thr browser reloads the page.

How can I fix this? I guess I should somehow wrap my routes that require authentication?...

**Update**

So I spent some time I came up with this logic:

```
ReactDOM.render((

    <div>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                <App>
                    <Route path="/timeline" component={Timeline} />
                    <Route path="/chat/:id" component={Chat} />
                </App>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </div>


), document.getElementById('root'))
```

My auth logic now lives in App.js and gets called only once when I try to open any route inside the `<App></App>` part.

Comment: Do you mean the screen blinks, what do you mean by reloading? Does it actually reload?

Comment: Well, I guess the question is incorrect. My actual problem is that requireAuth() fires everytime I go from one route to another.

Comment: Yes because you're wrapping it in a HOC. This will trigger every single time, no matter if it's been executed before because it must pass to render the child component.

Comment: I am actually seeing it now its quite obvious. Is there any way to combine the routes that need to be authenticated?

Comment: I've posted an answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of protecting your client side components, I would just protect the entry point via the same HOC and find another way to protect the inner workings of your app. It's very easy to bypass client side restrictions to access your protected components, therefore you can only do so much protection from this end.

The most popular way of solving this is to protect ANY request that is used to submit data to your backend with a token that must be verified before any data is successfully submitted.

Comment: Spent another hour or so and came up with this:

<Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
 
<App>
     
<Route path="/timeline" component={Timeline} />
     
<Route path="/chat/:id" component={Chat} />
    
</App>


I put my auth logic in App so it gets called only once and it acts as an entry point

Comment: @mikek Awesome! Glad to hear :)